# ADFS error after 10 min in login page: Encountered error during federation passive request

Tags: adfs, pingfederate

I am using PingFederate HTML FormAdapter and ADFS for a simple login page and user authentication. If the user keeps the login page open/idle for 10 or more minutes and enters credentials and clicks login, I am getting the below exception. If the login is before 10 minutes, it is working fine. Is there a timeout in ADFS that I can increase?

Encountered error during federation passive request.

Additional Data

Protocol Name: 
Saml

Relying Party:

Exception details: 
Microsoft.IdentityServer.Web.CookieManagers.InvalidContextException: MSIS7001: The passive protocol context was not found or not valid. If the context was stored in cookies, the cookies that were presented by the client were not valid. Ensure that the client browser is configured to accept cookies from this website and retry this request.
   at Microsoft.IdentityServer.Web.Protocols.Saml.SamlProtocolHandler.GetOriginalRequestFromResponse(ProtocolContext context, Boolean deleteCookie)
   at Microsoft.IdentityServer.Web.PassiveProtocolListener.ProcessProtocolRequest(ProtocolContext protocolContext, PassiveProtocolHandler protocolHandler)
   at Microsoft.IdentityServer.Web.PassiveProtocolListener.OnGetContext(WrappedHttpListenerContext context)

Answer (score 1):

I have seen this issue before. Some things to try:

1. Verify that the federation service is operating within its operating capacity.
2. Verify that it is not experiencing network outages.
3. Check that the IIS supports federation.

You can check this with:

```
setspn -L  <hostname>
```

This lists current SPNs.

If it is not there, set the SPN

```
setspn -a http/adfs <machine name> <service account name>
```

If there is an issue you can re-run the ADFS Proxy wizard and recreate the IIS sites.

4. Check that the ADFS app pool is running.

Check the troubleshooting guides:

https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/19057.ad-fs-2-x-troubleshooting-proxy-server-event-id-230-congestion-avoidance-algorithm.aspx

https://www.experts-exchange.com/questions/28657729/ADFS-Error-364-Encountered-error-during-federation-passive-request.html